# Bestimmung der Satzglieder

Tags: sentence-structure

Ich versuche, folgende Aufgabe zu lösen. Es müssen dabei die Satzglieder in folgendem Text bestimmt werden:

> Zum Schluss im Turnsaal vergnügt der Pirat mit der Hexe, der Vampir mit der Fee und der Indianer mit der Prinzessin tanzen.

Ich würde hier folgende Satzglieder bestimmen (jeweils durch Bindestrich getrennt):

Zum Schluss - im Turnsaal - vergnügt - der Pirat - mit der Hexe - der Vampir - mit der Fee - und  - der Indianer - mit der Prinzessin - tanzen

Ist diese Lösung korrekt? Gibt es eventuell verschiedene Lösungsmöglichkeiten oder ist das Bestimmen der Satzglieder immer eindeutig?

**Edit:** Ich habe vergessen zu erwähnen, dass neben dem Bestimmen der Satzglieder auch die richtige Ordnung gefragt ist. Daher ist dieser "Satz" in dieser Form noch nicht korrekt. Es ist mehr eine Aneinanderreihung von Wörtern, die zu Satzgliedern zusammengefasst und anschließend sortiert werden müssen.

Answer (score 3):

Ich weiß nicht, ob die Frage hier zulässig (erlaubt) ist. Jedenfalls würde ich so strukturieren - aber der Satz ist falsch, siehe unten:

> *(Zum Schluss (im Turnsaal)) vergnügt (der Pirat (mit der Hexe)), (der
> Vampir (mit der Fee)) und (der Indianer (mit der Prinzessin)) tanzen.

*Das Zeichen* " * " *bedeutet, dass der Satz falsch = ungrammatisch ist.*

Ich frage mich, wo du den Satz herhast (gefunden hast). Besser so:

> ?(Zum Schluss (im Turnsaal)) tanzen vergnügt (der Pirat (mit der
> Hexe)), (der Vampir (mit der Fee)) und (der Indianer (mit der
> Prinzessin))

*Das Zeichen " ? " *bedeutet, dass der Satz fragwürdig = nicht 100% richtig und nicht 100% falsch ist.*

Auch das ist noch keine ganz normale Wortstellung, besser:

> (Zum Schluss) tanzen (der Pirat (mit der Hexe)),
> (der Vampir (mit der Fee)) und (der Indianer (mit der Prinzessin))
> (vergnügt) (im Turnsaal).

Oder auch so, mit dem Prädikat als weiterem Satzglied und Umklammerung des gesamten Subjekts:

> (Zum Schluss) {tanzen} [(der Pirat mit der Hexe),
> (der Vampir mit der Fee) und (der Indianer mit der Prinzessin)]
> (vergnügt) (im Turnsaal).

"{ / }" bezeichnet hier das "Prädikat", aber darüber, was alles zum Prädikat gehört, gibt es verschiedene Ansichten.

Comment: Ich habe in der Frage ergänzt, dass auch die Sortierung der zuvor definierten Satzglieder Teil der Aufgabe ist.

Comment: Bedeuten die verschachtelten runden Klammern, dass man wahlweise 1 oder 2 Satzglieder bilden kann?

Comment: Ich bin nicht im Grammatiktheoriebusiness, daher die dezente Frage: Sollte man nicht noch eine äußere Klammer spendieren, für ((der Pirat (mit der Hexe)), (der Vampir (mit der Fee)) und (der Indianer (mit der Prinzessin))) := eine Aufzählung?

Comment: @user unknown . Hatte ich auch überlegt, aber ich dachte, da der Satz in sich nicht sehr klar ist, wollte ich den Aufwand für mich gering halten. Es ging ja nur um 'Satzglieder' nach einer nicht genau festgelegten Definition, damit kann man sowieso nicht viel bewerkstelligen, interessanter wäre da schon die Frage: welche Satzglieder sind es denn? Aber du hast recht, deine große Klammer umfasst das Subjekt, also das wäre durchaus eine gute Möglichkeit, ich glaube, ich nehm' das mal auf...

Comment: @Niki: So würde ich das machen, es geht ja um die Aufzählungen der Tanzpaare, das _mit_ wurde paarintern nur deswegen gewählt, weil das _und_ für die Paar-Aufreihung schon 'verbraucht' war. Ich hätte es vielleicht auch so lösen können: ((der Pirat) (mit der Hexe)), oder sogar {tanzen} (der Pirat) (mit der Hexe) usw. denn gäbe es nur ein Tanzpaar, wäre die Basisstruktur (A) {tanzt} (mit B) - _A: = Subj,, _mit B_ = Modalergänzung (wie tanzt A); oder im Sinne von _A_ und _B_ betanzen sich reziprok / gegenseitig. Für mich sind diese _mit B_'s eine Art Apposition, aber das ist Auffassungssache.

Comment: @Niki: Man kann das sicherlich noch auf vielfältige andere Weisen lösen. Tatsächlich bilden alle Paare hintereinander von _Pirat_ bis _Prinzessin_ das Satzglied "Subjekt", darauf hatte _user unknown_ hingewiesen, das wäre mit einer Über-Klammer und Unterklammern nur jeweils um die drei Paare herum die einfachste Lösung:  (Zum Schluss) ... {tanzen} [(der Pirat mit der Hexe), (der Vampir mit der Fee) und (der Indianer mit der Prinzessin)] (vergnügt) (im Turnsaal). Die Satzglieder wären dann: Zeitangabe, Prädikat, Subjekt (mit Paar 1 bis 3), Modalangabe, Ortsangabe...

Answer (score 1):

### Bestimmung der Satzglieder

Falls es hier ums Sprachenlernen und nicht um eine wissenschaftliche Auseinandersetzung mit der Syntax geht, würde ich folgende Aufteilung (nach Satzgliedern geordnet) vorschlagen:

- **Subjekt**: *der Pirat mit der Hexe, der Vampir mit der Fee und der Indianer mit der Prinzessin*
- **Prädikat**: *tanzen*
- **Adverbiale Bestimmung der Zeit**: *zum Schluss*
- **Adverbiale Bestimmung der Art und Weise**: *vergnügt*
- **Adverbiale Bestimmung des Ortes**: *im Turnsaal*

Zum Thema Subjekt: In einer Phrase wie *der Pirat [tanzt] mit der Hexe* gehört *mit der Hexe* eher zum Prädikat als zum Subjekt (Gegenbeispiel: *der Pirat **mit der Augenklappe** [tanzt] mit der Hexe*; ersteres *mit* gehört zum Subjekt). Da die Paare hier aber so betont hintereinander genannt werden, würde ich es nicht zu kompliziert machen und aus praktischen Gründen die einfachere, ggf. vom Ersteller intendierte und ebenso vertretbare Lösung wählen.

### Reihenfolge:

Die eben im ersten Abschnitt genannte Reihenfolge ist möglich:

> Der Pirat mit der Hexe, der Vampir mit der Fee und der Indianer mit der Prinzessin tanzen zum Schluss vergnügt im Turnsaal.

Gibt es einen Kontext für den Satz? Je nachdem, was betont werden soll, kommen auch folgende Reihenfolgen in Betracht (sog. "markierte" Satzstellungen):

> - Zum Schluss tanzen der Pirat mit der Hexe, der Vampir mit der Fee und der Indianer mit der Prinzessin vergnügt im Turnsaal.
> - Im Turnsaal tanzen zum Schluss vergnügt der Pirat mit der Hexe, der Vampir mit der Fee und der Indianer mit der Prinzessin.
> - Vergnügt tanzen der Pirat mit der Hexe, der Vampir mit der Fee und der Indianer mit der Prinzessin zum Schluss im Turnsaal.

Comment: Ich denke, dass die erstgenannte Reihenfolge nicht möglich ist. Das wird vor allem sichtbar, indem man das Ganze auf ein Tanzpaar verkürzt:  _Der Pirat mit der Hexe tanzt zum Schluss vergnügt im Turnsaal._ Rein syntaktisch wäre das (vielleicht?) möglich, aber die Thema-Rhema-Verteilung wäre, wie man's auch dreht und wendet, unplausibel. Ersetzt man das _mit_ durch _und_ und passt das Verb an (tanzen), stellt sich das Problem nicht. Durch ein _mit_ wird der jeweilige Tanzpartner fokussiert und automatisch rhematisiert, er gelangt so in die Satzaussage (ins Prädikat). Allenfalls ginge: ...

Comment: ... _Mit der Hexe tanzt der Pirat am Schluss / tanzt am Schluss der Pirat vergnügt im Turnsaal._